# SplashScreen compat library with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to properly use the SplashScreen compat library (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/splash-screen-migration#splashscreen_compat_library) with Jetpack Compose? It is desirable to immediately call `setContent` in `onCreate`, like so:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen()

        setContent {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, `setContent` replaces the root view when it finishes loading. Therefore, the splash screen exit animation does not finish. The alternative is to call `setContent` when the exit animation finishes, but this is inefficient. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been fixed with version 1.0.0-alpha02 of the library. See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#core-splashscreen-1.0.0-alpha02 for details.